# Can't login or sign up to Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

I just imported my form from Adobe FormsCentral. I did a bunch of edits and now cannot login (I thought I created a login along the way) and cannot sign up either. There is just an empty blue page with a header—no matter what route I take to get to the page. I'm using the latest version of Safari.

I'm concerned that the work I entered may get lost.

---

Not sure how this whole help site works---so here is addendum to my question.

There are TWO issues here:

1. I can't create an account or login through Safari--despite clearing cookies etc. which I've done many times now. I do have the developer plugin on Safari (although I'm ill equipped to use it) I could provide info from that plugin if you were really specific about what you wanted.
2. I created an account through Firefox BUT see no way to either import my form from Adobe FormsCentral OR to access the one I WAS able to import and edit in Safari originally, (which now seems to be lost since I cannot even create an account or login)

I think the problem here is that you allow people to import their file from Adobe FormsCentral (which is how I started) and then later they are required to create an account after they do a bunch of edits (which is what happened to me) and then there is a problem with even accessing the form to create an account (blank page)

Please let me know if you think this can be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Barbara, great to hear from you!  I'm sorry to hear that you encountered a problem while importing a form. Cognito Forms generally handles the vast majority of form imports from FormsCentral without a hitch - but every once in a while we run into a particular form that might cause problems.  If you could let me know what your organization name is, I can look through our logs to determine what specifically might be causing the problem that you are seeing.  You might also want to try clearing the cookies in your browser and attempting to [log in](https://www.cognitoforms.com/login).

<sub>Disclaimer: I'm a member of the Cognito Forms team</sub>

Comment: It appears that the problem with signing in or logging in is with Safari (8.0.5) There login/signup page is empty. I DO see a login/signup form with Firefox. So I created an account. Contact Point Assoc LLC. But I see no way to link this account to the form I imported from Adobe FormsCentral. I also am concerned about the interface with Safari--since that is my main browser. Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure how this help system works here--is there someone at Cognito Forms who will get back with me? I'd still like to link my form from Adobe FormsCentral to  my account. And would like to use Safari if possible. I need to decide on whether Cognito Forms will work for me or not.

Comment: @Barbara'Bobbi'Bouchet, we did some testing on our end with Safari 8.0.5 on MacOS X Yosemite and were able to log in.  It may be that you have an active invalid session in Safari.  Could you try clearing your cookies then accessing the site?